# Improvements for conveyor belt in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, animations, fun, code-review

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \foreach \n in {0,-10,...,-720}
    {
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \useasboundingbox (-3,-3) rectangle (10,4);
                \draw[thick] (0,0) circle(1);
                %               \draw (0,0) -- (\n:1) node[fill=black,circle,inner sep=1pt] {} -- (-.5,{sin(\n)+2.5}) node[draw,rectangle,fill=white,minimum width=.5cm,minimum height=.7cm] {};
                \draw (-3,2.5) -- (-.5,{sin(\n)+2.5}) -- (\n:1) node[fill=black,circle,inner sep=1pt] {} -- (0,0);
                \foreach \x in {0,30,...,330}
                {
                    \draw (0,0) -- (\x+\n:1);
                }
                    \begin{scope}[xshift=2.5cm]
                        \foreach \y in {0,1.5,...,6}
                        {
                            %               \draw (\y,0) circle(.5);
                            %               \foreach \x in {0,30,...,330}
                            %               {
                            %                   \draw (\y,0) -- ([xshift=\y cm]\x+\n:.5);
                            %               }
                            \foreach \x in {0,40,...,320}
                            {
                                \fill (\y,0) -- ([xshift=\y cm]\x+\n:.5) arc(\x+\n:\x+\n+20:.5) -- cycle;
                            }
                            \fill (\y,0) circle(.4);
                        }
                        \draw[thick] (0,.5) -- (6,.5) arc(90:-90:.5) -- (0,-.5) arc(-90:-270:.5);
                    \end{scope}
                \draw[rotate=-60,thick] (0,.25) arc(90:270:.25) --+ (2.5,0) arc(-90:90:.25) -- cycle;
                \pgfmathsetmacro\xshift{cos(60)*2.5}
                \pgfmathsetmacro\yshift{-sin(60)*2.5}
                    \draw[xshift=\xshift cm,yshift=\yshift cm,rotate=60,thick] (0,.25) arc(90:270:.25) --+ (2.5,0) arc(-90:90:.25) -- cycle;
                \draw[thick,shift={({cos(60)*2.5},{-sin(60)*2.5})}] (0,0) circle(.25);
                \draw[fill=white,thick] (0,0) circle(.25);
                \foreach \x in {0,40,...,320}
                {
                    \draw (0,0) -- (\x+\n:.25);
                }
                \begin{scope}[shift={({cos(60)*2.5},{-sin(60)*2.5})}]
                    \foreach \x in {0,40,...,320}
                    {
                        \draw (0,0) -- (\x+\n:.25);
                    }
                \end{scope}
                \pgfmathsetmacro\shift{2*cos(60)*2.5}
                \pgfmathsetmacro\anothershift{-5.5*(\n/720)}
                    \fill[xshift=\shift cm,xshift=\anothershift cm,yshift=.5cm,rounded corners,red] (0,0) rectangle (.5,.3);
            \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image: Screenshot]

My question is: How can be the lever, which rotates the whole mechanism, be better drawn in meaning of how can be the realistic length be kept, because the part is hard coded and I'm looking for a more precisely solution.

Comment: What do you mean by realistic?  More like a piston driven crankshaft?

Comment: @John_Kormylo: Exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The length of the connecting arm is set by `\lenA`.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}

    \foreach \n in {0,-10,...,-720}
    {
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \useasboundingbox (-3,-3) rectangle (10,4);
                \draw[thick] (0,0) circle(1);
                %               \draw (0,0) -- (\n:1) node[fill=black,circle,inner sep=1pt] {} -- (-.5,{sin(\n)+2.5}) node[draw,rectangle,fill=white,minimum width=.5cm,minimum height=.7cm] {};
                \def\lenA{3}%
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\yB}{sin(\n)}%
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\xB}{cos(\n)}%
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\xA}{\xB-sqrt(\lenA*\lenA-\yB*\yB)}%
                \draw[blue] (\xA,0) -- (\xB,\yB);
                %\draw (-3,2.5) -- (-.5,{sin(\n)+2.5}) -- (\n:1) node[fill=black,circle,inner sep=1pt] {} -- (0,0);% levers
                \foreach \x in {0,30,...,330}% spokes
                {
                    \draw (0,0) -- (\x+\n:1);
                }
                    \begin{scope}[xshift=2.5cm]
                        \foreach \y in {0,1.5,...,6}
                        {
                            %               \draw (\y,0) circle(.5);
                            %               \foreach \x in {0,30,...,330}
                            %               {
                            %                   \draw (\y,0) -- ([xshift=\y cm]\x+\n:.5);
                            %               }
                            \foreach \x in {0,40,...,320}
                            {
                                \fill (\y,0) -- ([xshift=\y cm]\x+\n:.5) arc(\x+\n:\x+\n+20:.5) -- cycle;
                            }
                            \fill (\y,0) circle(.4);
                        }
                        \draw[thick] (0,.5) -- (6,.5) arc(90:-90:.5) -- (0,-.5) arc(-90:-270:.5);
                    \end{scope}
                \draw[rotate=-60,thick] (0,.25) arc(90:270:.25) --+ (2.5,0) arc(-90:90:.25) -- cycle;
                \pgfmathsetmacro\xshift{cos(60)*2.5}
                \pgfmathsetmacro\yshift{-sin(60)*2.5}
                    \draw[xshift=\xshift cm,yshift=\yshift cm,rotate=60,thick] (0,.25) arc(90:270:.25) --+ (2.5,0) arc(-90:90:.25) -- cycle;
                \draw[thick,shift={({cos(60)*2.5},{-sin(60)*2.5})}] (0,0) circle(.25);
                \draw[fill=white,thick] (0,0) circle(.25);
                \foreach \x in {0,40,...,320}
                {
                    \draw (0,0) -- (\x+\n:.25);
                }
                \begin{scope}[shift={({cos(60)*2.5},{-sin(60)*2.5})}]
                    \foreach \x in {0,40,...,320}
                    {
                        \draw (0,0) -- (\x+\n:.25);
                    }
                \end{scope}
                \pgfmathsetmacro\shift{2*cos(60)*2.5}
                \pgfmathsetmacro\anothershift{-5.5*(\n/720)}
                    \fill[xshift=\shift cm,xshift=\anothershift cm,yshift=.5cm,rounded corners,red] (0,0) rectangle (.5,.3);
            \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\end{document}
```